# Android 8.0 fragment transaction not working

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

On a Galaxy S8+ with Android 7.0, the following line executes correctly to refresh my fragment:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(myFragment).attach(myFragment).commit();
```

On another Galaxy S8+ with Android 8.0, the fragment doesnt seem to refresh at all, and I must manually remove the fragment and re-open it.. this is driving me bonkers, has anyone got any idea why Android 8.0 is doing this and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this is working, but if I break it up to two calls and (important) use commitNow() instead of commit(), it works as it used to on previous API

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(myFragment).commitNow();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(myFragment).commitNow();
```

If anyone sees a better solution please please let me know.  For some reason I don't sit right in my head with this fix, but I'm going to use it unless someone tells me why I shouldn't!